# How to get only one record instead of fetching 2 records when using IN

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on sql query in mysql for example I am inserting records like key and values pair

Student Table

```
StdId StuName   phnNum 
1    John   87678
```

I am storing detailed Info about that student in student_metadata table

```
S.NO FieldName   FieldValue     indexVal
1    college       St.Anns         1
2    Address      Arizona      1
3    IdNum         321             1
```

Now I want to fetch student_metadata

```
SELECT 
 student.stdId AS StdId
 fieldValue AS fieldValue
FROM 
Student 
 LEFT JOIN 
 Student_metadata ON Student.StdId = student_metadata.indexVal
Where 
 Student_metadata.fieldName IN ('College','IdNum')
```

Here my problem is If I use 'IN' it gives me 2 rows. like the below

```
StudentId  fieldValue 
1       St.Anns
1           321
```

I want to fetch like the below

```
StudentId  fieldValue IdNum
1       St.Anns    321
```

Can any one suggest me in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to pivot:

```
select 
 s.stdid,
 max(case when m.fieldname = 'College' then fieldvalue end) as fieldvalue,
 max(case when m.fieldname = 'IdNum' then fieldvalue end) as idnum
from student s
left join student_metadata m on s.stdid = m.indexval
where m.fieldname in ('College','IdNum')
group by s.stdid
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It working. can you explain why we are using max() function here.

Comment: Max is an aggregation function, which means it returns single value per group. In this case, a group is defined by stdid. So, it returns one fieldvalue per stdid. In your case, there are two separate rows one with fieldname College and other with IdNum. To 'flatten' the multiple rows to a single row, we use grouping and a suitable aggregate function. Some DBMS provide built in support for this functionality called **PIVOT**. You can look it up on google to learn more.

Comment: can you kindly give me suggestion of this case , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039971/how-to-use-in-in-sql-query-when-table-has-key-values-pairs/47040037?noredirect=1#comment81026854_47040037

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **pivot table** style query:

```
SELECT
    a.`StuName`,
    COALESCE(b.`FieldVal`) as `college`,
    COALESCE(c.`FieldVal`) as `IdNum`
FROM `Student` a
LEFT JOIN `student_metadata` b
ON b.`indexVal` = a.`StdId` AND b.`FieldName` = 'college'
LEFT JOIN `student_metadata` c
ON c.`indexVal` = a.`StdId` AND c.`FieldName` = 'IdNum'
WHERE a.`StdId` = 1
GROUP BY a.`StdId`
```