# How to use IN in sql query when table has key , values pairs

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a query which is having key value pairs

student

```
StdId StuName   phnNum 
1     John       87678
```

student_meta_data

```
S.NO field_name   field_value     StdId  
1    college       St.Anns         1       
2    Address      Arizona          1       
3    IdNum         321             1       
4    Subject         Maths         1        
5    Marks          90             1
6   Subject        Physics         1
7   Marks          80              1
```

I would like to fetch data from student_meta_data table, for this I had written query like the below,

```
select 
   case when student_meta_data.field_name = 'Subject' Then field_value end as subject
   case when student_meta_data.field_name ='Marks' Then field_value end as marks
   case when student_meta_data.field_name = 'IdNum' Then field_value end as IdNum
 from student_meta_data

 where student_meta_data.StdId=1
       && student_meta_data.field_name in ('Subject')
```

for the above query I am fetching records like the below,

```
subject   marks     IdNum
null      null      null
```

I am expecting to fetch records like below,

```
subject   marks     IdNum    
Maths      90        321       
Physics    80        321
```

can you one suggest in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: MAX(case...end) subject... GROUP BY something - and (obviously?) lose the subject condition at the end.

Comment: @Strawberry I tried using MAX(case ...)  function also. But its not working

Comment: If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i think you should remove the 2nd condition from where clause

Comment: @Harshil I tried by removing that also , but no luck

Comment: Obtaining subject and marks is straightforward. Do you absolutely need idNum? You'll need user variables to find the idnum

Comment: The problem is you use `&&` instead of `AND` but you dont really need the last condition anyway.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh You are right you need lot of variables to track those.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Yes I need IdNum also. But can you give a query which can fetch subject and marks.

Comment: @Chitti - Juan's answer looks good to me. Just try that.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/AJQ60708)

```
SELECT rn, 
       MAX(subject) as subject, 
       MAX(case when field_name = 'Marks' Then field_value end) as marks,
       MAX(idNum) as idNum

FROM ( SELECT m.*,
              @idNum := if(`field_name` = 'IdNum', `field_value`, @idNum) as idNum,
              @subject := if(`field_name` = 'Subject', `field_value`, @subject) as subject,
              @rn := if (@s = @subject, 
                         @rn,
                         if(@s := @subject, @rn+1, @rn+1)
                        ) as rn
       FROM student_meta_data m
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @idNum := 0, @rn := 0, @subject := '', @s := '' ) as var
       ORDER BY `SNO` ) as T
WHERE rn > 0       
GROUP BY rn;
```

**OUTPUT**

Using variable to track idNum and creating the groups for each subject. First query is just the inner subquery for debug propose, the final is your desire result

[image]

Comment: You dont need group by because you already filtering by `StdId=1` so `MAX()` will return the max of that set.

Comment: subject   marks     IdNum    
null         null         null

Comment: check this http://rextester.com/NCH6542 ... isnt the right answer but shouldnt return nulls. the problem I see there is no way to tell what mark correspond to which subject

Comment: Well, there may be a way.

Comment: @Strawberry You can use the `S.NO` order but then `IdNum`  only appear one time

Comment: only one record is there. I am expecting to get 2 records .how many subjects are there those ma subject   marks     IdNum    
Maths      90        321       
Physics    80        321

Comment: @chitti I know that. The problem is your data isnt normalized

Comment: yeah. All the `field_name` should be column instead of Rows.

Comment: @Strawberry I found a way, but isnt preatty.

Comment: This depend a lot from the data be on the right order. So use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model leaves a lot to be desired. Nevertheless, here's something to think about...

```
SELECT a.field_value subject
     , b.field_value marks 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) y_id 
         FROM student_meta_data x 
         JOIN student_meta_data y 
           ON y.id > x.id 
          AND y.field_name = 'marks' 
        WHERE x.field_name = 'subject' 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) a 
  JOIN student_meta_data b 
    ON b.id = a.y_id;
+---------+-------+
| subject | marks |
+---------+-------+
| Maths   | 90    |
| Physics | 80    |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: You are missing IdNum column

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I'm not missing anything

Comment: OP's desired result has IdNum. Your query doesn't have it.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Perhaps you failed to read my answer in its entirety.

Comment: I think @GurwinderSingh is right, you miss the idNum on the final result

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza If there is an omission, rest asssured that it is entirely deliberate.

Comment: I see .. But then you could say that instead of he fail to read the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I can't stress this enough, but your design needs a change. Normalize it.

---

*Derived from @Juan's answer.*

You can do this using user variables and simple filtering on that.

```
select idnum, subject, marks
from (
    select 
        @idnum   := if(field_name='IdNum', field_value, @idnum) as idnum,
        @subject := if(field_name='Subject', field_value, @subject) as subject,
        @marks   := if(field_name='Marks', field_value, @marks) as marks,
        m.field_name
    from student_meta_data
    cross join (
        select  @idnum   := 0, 
                @subject := null,
                @marks   := 0
        ) x
    order by sno
    ) t
where field_name = 'Marks';
```

I'm filtering based on just Marks field_name because it comes last in the given order and we'll have all the other required values set by then.

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8852/4)